# Validating XML against multiple XSD

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I have to validate a XML file against a schema. The problem is that the schema consists of 89 small .xsd files and is constructed using xsd:import (the size of the files is around 1kb). When I run my validator method the validation takes 30+ seconds. Is there any way to speed up the process?

Here's the code I use for validation:

```
public boolean checkXML(String XMLFileName, String XSDFileName) {
    Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(new File(XMLFileName));
    Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(new File(XSDFileName));
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
            .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    try {
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
        javax.xml.validation.Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(xmlFile);
        return true;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // Validation failed
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate an XML File Against Multiple Schema Definitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094893/validate-an-xml-file-against-multiple-schema-definitions)

Comment: @David: I don't think this is a duplicate of that one - this is about performance, not about making the functionality work.

Comment: If the OP is checking against individual 98 individual schemas one by one, I believe the answers in the other post _will_ improve performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why it could be taking a long time. It could be (as David Grant suggests) something to do with cycles of imports and includes. Or it could be one particularly nasty content model with numeric occurrence ranges. Or it could be a problem fetching a schema document such as the schema for the XML namespace from the W3C web site (the figure of 30 seconds rings a bell here, because the W3C site often takes that long to respond: they are trying to encourage you to use a local copy of the document).

Give it a try with Saxon and see if that does any better. (Sometimes Saxon does better than Xerces, sometimes it does worse; it would just be interesting to know, and it might help isolate the cause.)

Comment: seems the problem is indeed fetching a schema document from W3C. <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/> in this case. The problem is I am not allowed to modify the XSD and I'm not sure how can I fix this.

Comment: Saxon-EE 9.4 will use it's built in copy of the XML namespace schema. The alternative is to redirect the references using catalogs.

Comment: Thank you, Michael, I'll give it a try. I implemented a workaround by caching the Schema objects at the moment. Will give a try to Saxon as well.

Comment: SOLUTION https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61483586/validating-xml-against-multiple-xsdstored-as-resources-spring-boot/61483587#61483587

Answer (score 3):

You should start by understanding which of the class library calls takes the time. i.e. is it `SchemaFactory.newSchema()`? `Schema.newValidator()`? or `Validator.validate()`?

I am sure you will find it is one of the first two, not the third.

The obvious next step is to refactor your code so that you only create the Schema (and/or the Validator) once for a particular schema file, and then cache it for use each time XML is validated against that schema.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It seems that it's the SchemaFactory.newSchema(). Is there some other workaround than caching the schema?