# Validating XML against multiple XSD(stored as resources). Spring Boot

Tags: java, xml, spring, kotlin, xsd

I've spend a lot of time to validate `XML` against multiple `XSD` in Spring. Even when I give all `XSD` schemas to SchemaFactory it does not work because main schema can't see `import schema` declared in main XSD file. Even when I give this schemas as files it does not work, because `Spring's` resource files can't be resolved to absolute `path`.

```
<xs:import namespace="http://test.com/types" schemaLocation="types.xsd"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. First we need this dependency which can parse xsd schemas:

```
implementation("org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:2.2.4")
```

### 2. We create 2 beans. One for storing our `XSD's` (it will automatically find other files if there this `schemaLocation="..."`), another for our `Validator`:

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun schema(): XsdSchemaCollection {
        return CommonsXsdSchemaCollection(
            ClassPathResource("xsd/main.xsd")
        ).also { it.setInline(true) }
    }

    @Bean
    fun myValidator(schema: XsdSchemaCollection): XmlValidator {
        return schema.createValidator()
    }
```

### 3. And we can use it:

```
    @Autowired
    private val myValidator: XmlValidator

    fun validate(data: String): Array<SAXParseException> {
        return myValidator.validate(StreamSource(data.byteInputStream()))
    }
```

`Array<SAXParseException>` will contain list of validation exceptions if any of course