# Validate xml response/string against list of xsds using RestAssured

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, rest-assured

I am trying to validate an XML response retrieved from RestAssured with a list of XSDs which are referenced within.

I tried

```
 given().param(...).when().get(URL).then().assertThat().body(matchesXsd(xsd))
```

This works if I have one XSDs file which contains all schema definitions but how can I have multiple XSDs? These XSDs are also referenced within themselves. Also, all XSDs are local to the project.

I tried [Rest-Assured XSD References Other XSDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312613/rest-assured-xsd-references-other-xsds) and [Validate an XML File Against Multiple Schema Definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094893/validate-an-xml-file-against-multiple-schema-definitions) and few more but they were either irrelevant to my goal or didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by:

`given().param(...).when().get(URL).then().assertThat().body(matchesXsd(getSystemResourceAsStream("parent.xsd")).using(new ClasspathResourceResolver()));`

ClasspathResourceResolver resolves all references from parent XSD.

and

`

```
public class ClasspathResourceResolver implements LSResourceResolver {

    @Override
    public LSInput resolveResource(String type, String namespaceURI, String publicId, String systemId, String baseURI) {
        InputStream resource = getSystemResourceAsStream(systemId);
        return new DOMInputImpl(publicId, systemId, baseURI, resource, null);
    }
}
```

`