# Unmarshal xml file with Moxy validating against multiple XML schemas

Tags: java, xml, validation, unmarshalling, moxy

I am trying to unmarshal a XML file using EclipseLink MOXy 2.6 against multiple XML schemas - `common.xsd` and `userOfCommon.xsd`.
`userOfCommon.xsd` includes `common.xsd` and uses certain types defined in it.

I you want validation you have to set the unmarshaller like this:

```
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

Source common = new StreamSource(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("xsd/common.xsd"));
Source userOfCommon = new StreamSource(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("xsd/userOfCommon.xsd"));

Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new Source[] {common, userOfCommon});
unmarshaller.setSchema(sf.newSchema(schema));
```

But setting the schema gives an error saying "Failing to resolve the 'Some ComplexType Name' to a(n) 'type definition' component."

I tried to set the schema as a file name like this

```
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("xsd/userOfCommon.xsd"));
```

And it works. But I want to set the schema as Source items in order for it to be loaded from the classpath.

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: can you post content of `userOfCommon.xsd` and `common.xsd`?

Comment: Santhosh, actually the content of the schema files is irrelevant in this situation. The problem is not there. `userOfCommon.xsd` uses some type definitions from `common.xsd` and that's all. This issue persist even with the simplest configuration of a shema definition including another schema definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the answer given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1105871/4243908 works in this situation.

I had to set a custom ResourceResolver in the SchemaFactory like this

```
sf.setResourceResolver(new ResourceResolver());
```

The code for the ResourceResolver is available [here](http://code.google.com/p/xmlsanity/source/browse/src/com/arc90/xmlsanity/validation/ResourceResolver.java?r=03a92d97f15904b3892922e45724bb086d54fa4e)

In that case there is no need to import multiple schema sources. You can just import the main schema source like this:

```
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(userOfCommon);
```

However I still have not figured out how to achieve it with multiple schema sources and without using custom ResourceResolver.

Answer (score 0):

try using location while creating `StreamSource` as below:

```
Source common = new StreamSource(this.getClass().getResource("xsd/common.xsd").toString());
Source userOfCommon = new StreamSource(this.getClass().getResource("xsd/userOfCommon.xsd").toString());
```

the location is used to resolve schema imports relatively