# How to resolve included schema types in .xsd

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, schema

I have two `.xsd` files in the same `src/main/resource` folder:

1. outer.xsd
2. inner.xsd

`outer.xsd` looks like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:tns="http://project.domain.com/model" 
           targetNamespace="http://project.domain.com/model"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="inner.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="innerObject" type="tns:InnerObjectType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

and `inner.xsd` looks like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:model="http://project.domain.com/model"
           targetNamespace="http://project.domain.com/model"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
  <xs:complexType name="InnerObjectType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="property1" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="property2" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  <xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Now, in another project, I'm using `outer.xsd` to validate input XML files like so:

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
try {
    ClassLoader classLoader = objectType.getClassLoader();
    InputStream stream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(schemaPath);
    Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(stream);
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaSource);
    ...
} catch (SAXException exception) {...}
```

On the line where I call `newSchema`, I am getting the following exception:

```
src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'tns:InnerObjectType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
```

It appears that this code is able to find the outer schema by path, but during the process of resolving the inner type, it cannot find the inner schema.

Anybody have a suggestion of how I can get it to resolve that inner type?

Note: I was able to use `outer.xsd` to generate an XML file in eclipse, so I am relatively certain that the structure of the `.xsd` files is correct ... it's just that whatever the context is when `outer.xsd` is being resolved doesn't have access to `inner.xsd`.

A parallel question is: How can I find out what the context is in which the type is being resolved? (ie ... where is it looking for `inner.xsd`?)

Comment: This question [Validate an XML File Against Multiple Schema Definitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094893/validate-an-xml-file-against-multiple-schema-definitions) might contain the answer.

Comment: You r using element of type `"tns:InnerObjectType"` in `outer.xsd` with `xmlns:tns="http://project.domain.com/model"`, but your `InnerObjectType` is defined in `inner.xsd` with `targetNamespace="http://project.domain.com/model/model"`, which is different. In the first case the prefix path ends with **model**, in the second case the targetNamespace path ends with **model/model**.

Comment: Thanks @MockerTim ... it turns out that was just a typo in my question and isn't represented in the code.  I've fixed the typo in my question.

Comment: See my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59666291/2341765