# Java Validate XML Schema with XSDs that import each other

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, sax

I have the following xsd setup:

- root.xsd (imports layout.xsd & validation.xsd)
- layout.xsd (imports root.xsd)
- validation.xsd (imports root.xsd)

The real xsds cannot be modified and they are in use from years.

I am looking to validate an xml file against the xsd in Java.

Code (kotlin) looks like the following -

```
val factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
val schema = factory.newSchema(arrayOf(
   StreamSource(getResourceAsStream("validation.xsd")),
   StreamSource(getResourceAsStream("layout.xsd")),
   StreamSource(getResourceAsStream("root.xsd"))
))
```

The call to `newSchema` throws an error that it cannot resolve a type definition element declared in `root.xsd` while loading the first schema file `validation.xsd`. If I change the order of sources to first load `root.xsd` then I get the same error for a type declared in one of the other xsd files.

The only way to resolve this seems to be to include all of these in a single xsd file. This worked as expected but the xml file to be validated against these xsds has namespace declarations for the individual xsd files. Combining all of the xsds means that the namespace declarations on xml have to be updated. We are not allowed to make this update.

`xmllint` is able to successully run the validations

```
xmllint --schema  root.xsd ../sample.xml --noout
```

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is old, but may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1094893/18157